# Online Resume post successful offer

Tags: resume, job-search

I am recent graduate student who have secured a stable position at a financial firm. I have posted my resumes on online sites such as Monster, Dice, Indeed etc to aid employer exposure during my job search. **Is it advisable for me to take my resumes down or at least make it private so its invisible to recruiters / employers?**

Loyalty, given satisfaction with current role, is a very important part of professionalism and one's character. Leaving online resumes in public view goes against this loyalty concept.

On the other hand, however, it is a good idea not to take one's job for granted and be open in case one's current job goes under.

What is accepted view in regard to this matter?

Comment: um, loyalty has very little to do with professionalism per say, unless you're referring to *loyalty to the profession*. Professionalism implies a focus on the work, loyalty implies - as you use it - a focus on the company. The two can be divergent, even conflicting. I don't think anyone cares if you leave your profile on public view or not, recruiters will only look at profiles when they get *updated*. A month or two of no activity on your part and nobody will look at your CV, public or no.

Comment: "Leaving online resumes in public view goes against this loyalty concept." It doesn't go against mine. I have been laid often enough with zero notice and paltry severance to know better than trust my employer to be 100% reliable. Since your financial industry is full of recruiters who are making a pretty good penny on confidentiality and since employers can be contacted directly either by email or through networking, I presume that their concept and your concept of loyalty and professionalism includes some pretty effective workarounds.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On job sites, I keep the resumes private rather than taking them down entirely. This is only for convenience, since the next time I need to actively seek jobs, I only need to upload updated resumes and update a few fields, not fill up entire forms from scratch. Moreover, many job sites don't allow creating multiple accounts with the same email or phone number (even if the previous account was deleted), another hassle easily avoided by not taking down the account entirely.

Most job sites also provide a text field called Summary (or equivalent). I "cheat" to use it to leave a custom message for a potential recruiter (if the job site doesn't allow making the resume private or allows a "premium" recruiter to see private profiles anyway).

> Thanks for your interest in my profile. I have recently accepted a position, and not actively seeking a job change at the moment.

I do this only as a courtesy to the recruiter, since I don't feel good to have a recruiter call me only to find out that I am not interested. Recruiters spend majority of their working hours making phone calls to candidates and companies, and following up on interview calls, job offers, etc. so I prefer not to burden them with "wasted" calls.

I also don't see anything wrong in keeping online resumes in public on non-job sites, such as LinkedIn or a blog. A resume should be a "live" document, which you should always keep updating, whether you are actively looking for a job or not.

A common misconception about a resume is that it is a document meant only to get you an interview call. I would rather say, a resume is a document which provides a snapshot of your career. You *use* it with your job application when you seek a job. Much like how you use a Driver's License to prove your identity or age, but that is not why you get a Driver's License in the first place.